# How to grep a line with a backslash at the end of the line?

Tags: linux, regex, grep

I'm trying to grep a line with a backslash at the end of the line like:

```
abc\
def
ghij
...
```

I hope it can grep the line "abc\". I tried the command below but they didn't work.

```
grep -EHn "\\$" test_file
grep -PHn "\\$" test_file
```

How should I solve this problem? I just don't know the logic of escape character in grep. The expression did work in vim.

Answer (score 8):

```
grep '\\$' test_file
```

works fine for me on Solaris 9 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Single quotes and double quotes differ in which characters are taken literally or used as escape/special characters.

Comment: It doesn't work on mine. GNU grep 2.6.3. Red Hat

Answer (score 3):

I somehow overcame the problem by using below:

```
grep -Hn  "\\\\$"
```

But I'm not sure why four back slash would work here. It just worked.

Comment: Don't use double quotes here. Double quotes do not preserve literal `$`, \, and backticks. In your case, \\ becomes a \, and `\$` becomes a `$` *before* being passed to `grep`, and only then `grep` looks for `\$`. Try `echo "\\\\$"` to see why.

Answer (score 2):

From "`man grep`" command:

-F, --fixed-strings
Interpret PATTERNS as fixed strings, not regular expressions.

-o, --only-matching
Print  only  the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output
line.

Also, you have to surround your target with a single quote mark to capcher the exact character:

input:

```
$echo " this is a backslash -- > '\' " | grep -oF '\'
```

output:

```
\
```